# Doctrine custom type: How to load values from config file?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, custom-type

I'm using Doctrine 2 in a Symfony 2 environment.

I've created a custom data type which extends \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type. This data type should map an integer value stored in database to a specific string (like ENUM, but integer and string must be accessible).

At the moment the mapping of these values is hardcoded within the doctrine type using a class variable which holds and array.

```
class xyType extends \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type {
  public static $messageTypes = array(
    10 => "Wareneingang",
    20 => "Polstern",
    .
    .
    .
  }

  .
  .
}
```

Now I want to put this array into the config.yml of this bundle. But I don't know how to use Dependency Injection in this type class, to be able to access my config parameters in any way...

I hope you can help me. I'm also open for other ideas to implement this.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you cannot access DI in your type class, but there is bundle initialization stage where you can save your types from config to your static property. So i suggest using YourBundleExtension to solve this.

Comment: I tried some ways to follow your suggestion, but I'm not able to solve it this way.

Comment: Ok after some typing and testing I got it... Using a static variable in type and initialize it in YourBundleExtension. Thx